# Constant solution for an elliptic equation

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, linear-pde, elliptic-operators

Let $U$ be a open and connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with regular boundary. Consider the fallowing elliptic problem
$$
\Delta u + c(x) u = u^3, U\\
\hspace{2cm}u = 0, \partial U,
$$
where $c$ may change of sign.

- Supose that the bilinear form associated to the elliptic operator is coercise.
- Supode there is a solution $u \in H^1_{0}(U)$ of
  truncated problem
  $$
  \Delta u + c(x) u = (u^+)^3, U.\\
  $$

Under these hypotesis, I need to conclude the solution $u$ is not constant.

**What I have tried**:
From coercivity we can conclude the solution of truncated problem is nonnegative, in other words, $u^{+} = u$. Using this fact I just can resolve the problem assuming the function $c$ is not  constant. In fact, if $u$ is constant, say $u = k$, from the weak formulation
$$
\int_{U} \nabla u \nabla v + c u v = \int_{U} u^{3} v, \forall v \in H^{1}_{0}.
$$
we get
$$
\int_{U} c v = k^2\int_{U}  v, \forall v \in H^{1}_{0}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\int_{U} (c - k^2)v = 0, \forall v \in C^{\infty}_{0}(U).
$$
This implyes $c = k^2$, what is not true if we supose the function $c$ is not constant.

Comment: Is it $-\Delta$ or $+\Delta$ on the left-hand side? The pde and the weak formulation do not match.

Comment: The zero function solves both problems and it's constant. What about it?

Comment: Thank you! You are completally right.